# UDP vs TCP sockets requirements

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I'm having some trouble understanding some key concept of the computer networking.

A UDP server usually only needs one socket, whereas a basic TCP server
needs two sockets. Why is that?

If a TCP server were to support n simultaneous
connections, each from a dierent client host, how many sockets would the
TCP server need?

If you can help me understand it I will be more than happy!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

hello i’ll try to explain this in a simple manner

TCP is a connection oriented protocol, while UDP is not.
what’s the difference?

In TCP it client and server must be connected first before sending and receiving msgs.
In UDP it can send and receive msgs without securing connection between client and server.

In terms of sockets (basic Tx and Rx)
UDP:
Client - 1 socket for Rx and Tx
Server - 1 socket for Rx and Tx

TCP
Client - 1 socket for Rx and Tx
Socket - 1 socket (main socket) and possibly n sockets
n - depends on how many clients will connect to the server